# How to prove that there does not exist a term  such that $Γ \vdash $, where $Γ=\{\lnot  \mid  \in \} \cup \{\exists  \mid \}$

Tags: first-order-logic

I didn't get correct answers so I post here again. Let $L$ be a logic language with one unary predicate symbol , no constant symbols, no function symbols. Let $V$ be a set of variables. We define the set of wffs  $Γ=\{\lnot  \mid  \in \} \cup \{\exists  \mid \}$. Prove that there does not exist a term  such that $Γ\vdash$. Could someone please give me some hints? Much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Since there are no function symbols, $t$ must be equal to some variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prove it.

If we have $Γ=\{ ¬ |∈ \} \cup \{ ∃ \} ⊢ Rt$ we have also, by Completeness : $Γ \vDash Rt$.

This means that $Γ \cup \{ \lnot Rt \}$ is *unsatisfiable*.

But has been [already shown](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3427847/is-the-set-of-wffs-%ce%93-%c2%acry-y-%e2%88%88-v-%e2%88%aa-%e2%88%83x-rx-satisfiable) that it is *satisfiable*, due to the fact that the language has no constants and no functions symbols, but only variables.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I'm more clear now.